# Error:(51, 39) The method setText(CharSequence) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments (List<User>)

Tags: android

am trying to add json object on my spinner but its giving proper result as per my way i am following tutoreal of https://inducesmile.com/android/populate-android-spinner-data-from-remote-mysql-database/please suggest me.

```
@SerializedName("Status")
@Expose
private String status;
@SerializedName("ExpiryDate")
@Expose
private String expiryDate;
@SerializedName("MessagesLeft")
@Expose
private String messagesLeft;
@SerializedName("Users")
@Expose
private List<User> users = null;
@SerializedName("Balance")
@Expose
private String balance;

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getExpiryDate() {
    return expiryDate;
}

public void setExpiryDate(String expiryDate) {
    this.expiryDate = expiryDate;
}

public String getMessagesLeft() {
    return messagesLeft;
}

public void setMessagesLeft(String messagesLeft) {
    this.messagesLeft = messagesLeft;
}

public List<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}

public String getBalance() {
    return balance;
}

public void setBalance(String balance) {
    this.balance = balance;
}
```

}

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
```

import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class User {

```
@SerializedName("username")
@Expose
private String username;

@SerializedName("userid")
@Expose
private String userid;

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getUserid() {
    return userid;
}

public void setUserid(String userid) {
    this.userid = userid;
}
```

}
and Adpater Class is that.

```
public class SpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private List<GetBalance> listData;
private Context context;
public SpinnerAdapter(Context context, List<GetBalance> listData) {
    this.context = context;
    layoutInflater =(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.listData = listData;
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listData.size();
}
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return (GetBalance)listData.get(position);
}
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder spinnerHolder;
    if(convertView == null){
        spinnerHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_list, parent, false);
        spinnerHolder.spinnerItemList = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_list_item);
        convertView.setTag(spinnerHolder);
    }else{
        spinnerHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    spinnerHolder.spinnerItemList.setText(listData.get(position).getUsers());
    return convertView;
}
class ViewHolder{
    TextView spinnerItemList;
}
```

}

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Error:(51, 39) The method setText(CharSequence) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments (List<User>)

Comment: am coufued in to model how to call the model data using gson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are trying to set list data to a TextView view.Instead of that try this statment,where position will the user position that you want to display

```
spinnerHolder.spinnerItemList.setText(listData.get(position).getUsers().get(position).getUsername());
```

Comment: let me try this

Comment: ohk..try it and let me know

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set list to textview which is not possible ,try following code to settext

```
spinnerHolder.spinnerItemList.setText(listData.get(position).getUsers().get(0).getUsername());
```